# How to have your user script deal with functions and elements that don't exist yet?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

When writing user scripts for various websites I often come across the problem of dealing with elements or JS functions that don't exist yet at the time of execution. I'd like to know how to get to those functions or elements.
An obvious solution is a `setTimeout`, but that's very inelegant. I've also experimented with the various events like `DOMContentLoaded` and `window.onload`, but I often find that these events are still too early, due to content and code being dynamically generated/loaded afterwards.

Comment: implement custom events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059456/how-do-i-create-a-custom-event-class-in-javascript

Comment: Wha…? How would I know when to fire it??

Comment: If you have access to the code that is dynamically generated/loaded after dom ready, trigger the custom event. you should also listen for the event before the dynamic content has begun to load. alternatively using `setInterval` to keep checking for the existence of what you want should do the trick, although this will cause quite a bit of overhead (relatively speaking) - subsequently clear the interval when successful.

Comment: There's an event called `DOMSubtreeModified`. IIRC, I have read somewhere that its deprecated. This will probably work for you.

Comment: For elements, you can use Mutation Observers.  For javascript you could use intercept and replace **on Firefox only**.  Otherwise in both cases, interval polling is really the best, most robust, and straightforward solution.  See the [the waitForKeyElements() utility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508) for an easy implementation. (It's for elements. Adapt it for JS objects too, if needed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that whatever you're loading emits an event, that you can hook into.

If you're loading a script file you can hook into the `onload` event. If you do an AJAX call you can hook into the `onreadystatechange` event.

These are some useful native events.

You can also make more custom events by using Promises.

```
var modules = {/* */};
var foo = modules.load("foo"); // returns a promise
foo.done(function (foo_module) {
    // we now have the foo-module
});
```

[requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) might be worthwhile to look at, just to see how they do things.

As for promises, this is a good read: [What’s so great about JavaScript Promises?](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/)

Comment: The OP can't "Make sure that whatever you're loading emits an event, that you can hook into."  This is a **userscripts** question.  The OP does not control the target page.

Comment: In that case, I like the idea of using mutation observers. My answer doesn't change much, just that origin of your event is 2nd-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not doing something wrong before jumping to conclusions. Like, remember that user scripts in Chrome for example, are sandboxed, and you'll need to jump through a hoop or two to even access code on the target page. For small scripts, I suggest the "Location Hack". https://stackoverflow.com/a/5006952/125938